# Making list empty after return in function

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have one trouble in my program I´m currently working on. I need to make a function, which flatten a list whom items can contain lists again, into a one simple list. Function gets a list as a parameter and I need to return new flattened list without changing the main one, using recursion.

This is my current attempt:

```
 result = []

def flatten(nested_list):
    for i in nested_list:
        if type(i) != list:
            result.append(i)
        else:
            flatten(i)
    return result
```

The problem here is, as soon as I want to run this function again, it remembers the last result, what means that it appends everything at the end. But I want to make a new result, containing just a simple list of current nested one. How can I remove last result when calling function again?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the marked question, it is only tangentially related.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you are always using a global variable. Using mutable global scope is generally an anti-pattern. Keeping your code essentially the same. An easy approach is to use an accumulator and pass it as an argument to your recursive calls:

```
In [4]: def flatten(nested_list, result=None):
   ...:     if result is None:
   ...:         result = []
   ...:     for i in nested_list:
   ...:         if type(i) != list:
   ...:             result.append(i)
   ...:         else:
   ...:             flatten(i, result)
   ...:     return result
   ...:
   ...:

In [5]: x = [[1,[2], [3,4],5]]

In [6]: flatten(x)
Out[6]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [7]: x
Out[7]: [[1, [2], [3, 4], 5]]

In [8]: flatten(x)
Out[8]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [9]: x
Out[9]: [[1, [2], [3, 4], 5]]
```

Often, though, you don't want to expose `result` as a parameter waiting for you to shoot yourself in the foot. So, you can define a "private" helper function:

```
In [15]: def _flatten(nested_list, result):
    ...:     for i in nested_list:
    ...:         if type(i) != list:
    ...:             result.append(i)
    ...:         else:
    ...:             _flatten(i, result)
    ...:     return result
    ...:
    ...: def flatten(nested_list):
    ...:     return _flatten(nested_list, [])
    ...:
    ...:

In [16]: x = [[1,[2], [3,4],5]]

In [17]: flatten(x)
Out[17]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [18]: x
Out[18]: [[1, [2], [3, 4], 5]]

In [19]: flatten(x)
Out[19]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or, you can define your helper inside your main function, and squirrel your result variable in a closure:

```
In [26]: def flatten(nested_list):
    ...:     result = []
    ...:     def _flatten(nested_list):
    ...:         for i in nested_list:
    ...:             if type(i) != list:
    ...:                 result.append(i)
    ...:             else:
    ...:                 _flatten(i)
    ...:
    ...:     _flatten(nested_list)
    ...:     return result
    ...:
    ...:

In [27]: flatten(x)
Out[27]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [28]: x
Out[28]: [[1, [2], [3, 4], 5]]

In [29]: flatten(x)
Out[29]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are experiencing this problem is because `result` is in the wrong [scope](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html). You need to put the `result` declaration inside the function so that when the function ends, it goes out of scope and no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks. But how to add anything after function return?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a global variable, extra argument, private helper function, nor a closure -- just know when to use `append()` and when to use `extend()`:

```
def flatten(nested_list):
    result = []

    for i in nested_list:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            result.extend(flatten(i))
        else:
            result.append(i)

    return result
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
>>> x = [[1, [2], [3, 4], 5]]
>>> flatten(x)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> x
[[1, [2], [3, 4], 5]]
>>>
```

Also `if type(i) != list:` probably isn't the type check of choice these days -- `isinstance()` will work with subclasses as well.